# Imprimir día por día de una semana con PHP

Tags: php

necesito puedan colaborarme con una solución a mi consulta.

Resulta que tengo una semana que siempre será Domingo a Sábado para una agenda de forma horizontal. Pero necesito imprimir el día según la semana. actual.

Ya tengo el código de semana actual el cual es:

```
    if(date('D')!='Mon'){    
        $staticstart = date('d/m/Y',strtotime('last Sunday'));    
    }else{
        $staticstart = date('d/m/Y');   
    }
    if(date('D') != 'Sun') {
        $staticfinish = date('d/m/Y',strtotime('next Saturday'));
    }else{
        $staticfinish = date('d/m/Y');
    }
```

Ahora bien, cómo imprimo de forma horizontal el día según el rango. Adjunto imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] de referencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si entendí bien. ¿Quieres imprimir el rango de días de la semana, de domingo a sábado de una fecha en particular?
Si es así, esta función te puede servir, ayudándonos del constructor DateTime, el cual permite hacer muchas operaciones con fechas. El código es sencillo y en él está documentado lo que hace.

```
<?php
function date_week($u_date) {
    $date_obj = new DateTime($u_date); // Crear un objeto de fecha
    $num_day = $date_obj->format('w'); // 0-dom, 1-lun, ... 6-sab
    $date_obj->modify("-$num_day day"); // Posicionar el objeto en domingo
    $wdays = array();
    for($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
        $wdays[] = $date_obj->format('Y-m-d');
        $date_obj->modify('+1 day'); // Incrementar el objeto 1 dia
    }
    return $wdays;
}
```

Ejemplos de salida:

```
print_r(date_week('2020-04-03')); 
// array('2020-03-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04')
print_r(date_week('2020-12-30')); 
// array('2020-12-27', '2020-12-28', '2020-12-29', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-02')
```

El `array` de salida puedes recorrerlo con un ciclo y aplicarle los formatos HTML correspondientes.

[ Edit ] Modifiqué el formato de salida a completo `Y-m-d` por si quieres hacer otras cosas con esa fecha, como especificar el mes o el año si cambia. En caso de querer imprimir solo el día, pues solo basta con `substr($array[$i], -2);` a cada elemento, o también da lo mismo:  `date('d', strtotime($array[$i]));`

Función [Date y Formatos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) | Constructor [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: Justo como lo necesitaba, te agradezco mucho la solución.

Comment: @Alejandro modifiqué el formato de salida a fecha completa, por si quieres hacer operaciones con esa fecha, como cuando cambia el mes, o el año. Ahí tu puedes jugar con los formatos de fecha que existan y satisfacen tus necesidades.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando `DateTime` no esta disponible, con el viejo fiel `mktime` tienes la semana en dos líneas:

```
$semana = array(); // Arreglo de timestamps
for($d=0; $d<7 ; $d++)
  $semana[] = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('d')-date('w')+$d, date('Y'));

foreach($semana as $dia)
  echo date('d/m/Y',$dia).PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda aplicar la función

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php para establecer la zona horaria desde la que trabajas, siempre que trabajemos con fechas en php.